# Programmatically getting "Operating System Context" in C++

Tags: c++, windows

How can in retrieve the **Operating system context** for my application programmatically?

[image]

Comment: I'd say that informations is part of the *application manifest*. Have you checked this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ?

Comment: @thokra yes exactly: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2009/03/27/manifesting-for-compatibility-on-windows-7.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: @Vinzenz: yay, linux guy did good. :)

Comment: That would've been fine if it was my app. But My app is a DLL that is injected into other processes ,Also the user can bypass the manifest decision if he runs the program in compatibility mode.

Comment: Please check this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724429(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Roger - wouldn't that page imply that it would not be possible to get the output shown in the picture? I.e The picture shows 3 different values for Operating System Context - yet that link doesn't show a way of specifying the target app - it appears to show information on the OS, rather than the context elected to run the program in. :curious:

Answer (score 1):

As others have posted this site answers the question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx

Use the Version Helper API

To know whether this will actually suit your needs though -Why- you want to do this needs to be examined. If this is related to feature support testing, then you may want to read the suggestions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx. The article discusses some various ways to perform feature detection such as:

1. A combination of [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. [GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) e.g. GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS)

Of course, this is more relevant if you are directly coding outside of the .NET world.